# Service account to connect database in winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

This looks a very common question but could not find any proper answer.

We have many WinForms apps that are currently using sql server account to connect sql. Now we are planning to use service accounts (active directory) to connect to DB. There is one option where we could provide each user access to the database and use integrated security which certainly we don't want. What could be the best solution considering that no/minimum change is required in the app?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Integrated security probably isn't as bad as you think. You set up a **group** in Active Directory, grant the group access to your database, and make your users members of that group. You can also use, say, just three of four groups for tiers of access.

Comment: What @JoelCoehoorn said. In addition, if you are to secure your database objects, do NOT secure them with Active Directory groups directly! Secure them with a database role (assuming SQL Server), and make the AD groups members of those roles. Otherwise, let's say you want to do a backup of PROD to a DEV server with DEV AD groups (i.e. MyApp_DataReader_Test). If you drop the production MyApp_DataReader group on the DEV SQL Server, your database objects will lose ALL permissions. This won't happen with database roles. Just have your DB restore script add the Test AD groups to the database role.

Comment: So, for each AD group, create one database role (e.g. for AD group MyApp_DataReader create SQL Server database role myapp_datareader).

Comment: *Why* don't you want to provide individual user access? The mechanism is the same as service accounts, but gives you more information and control for less work.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.

Sql accounts are less desirable in this situation because you have to distribute the account credential with your app. You can do things with encrypted config file sections or other tricks, but ultimately that username/password are exposed and not easily serviceable.

Integrated security improves on this by using the authentication infrastructure built into Active Directory. You no longer need to distribute passwords with your app.

However, there are still two weaknesses with Integrated Security.

The first is account management. It can be tedious to set up Sql Server logins for each of your Active Directory users, and awkward and unwieldy to manage them as you have user churn over time.

Thankfully, this isn't as bad as you might think. You can get past the issue by creating Sql Server logins for Active Directory groups instead of individual users. Setting an Active Directory user as a member of such a group is enough to grant them the group access. You can even use a small number of groups, one in place of each "Service Account" in your original proposal, in order to support tiered access. Using this scheme, the actual logged in user is also still available to Sql Server (and therefore to the application) for assigning more specific permissions within the app if needed.

The other weakness is you are granting raw database permissions directly to users, instead of merely granting permission to use an application. This is a real problem, if Joe User can download Sql Server Management Studio (or any similar app that may not even require installation) and run whatever query they want against the section of your database authorized for use of the app.

Unfortunately, your proposed solution (Service Accounts in Active Directory) won't work. Those service accounts still need to use integrated security, and integrated security **only** works when the account in question is actually running the application process. That's **never** going to work the way you want it to.

So what can we do?

One "best practice" is using [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/application-roles) in combination with group-based integrated security. Unfortunately, this requires changes to your application so every database connection can call `sp_setapprole`.

This also has you back to distributing a credential with your application. It's somewhat safer because this distributed credential requires the integrated security login before it can be used; if such a credential leaks to the world, your database is still only compromised among your own user base.

Keep in mind, though, when the credential is exposed any of your users with motivation and access to Google can still find an app that will let them replicate what your application was doing to run any query they want with the same permissions as the application, just as with group-based integrated security alone. You still need to protect the credential, and all the challenges going with that.

In other words, this still ultimately has both the integrated security weakness of granting raw database permissions to your users and the sql authentication weakness of needing to protect a credential. I'm not a fan.

There are two other options I know, but both requires significant modifications to the application.

The first option involves re-writing the application to use a service layer (usually JSON via web API) instead of direct database access. This works because you control the service layer machine(s), but it's a *huge* rewrite of the application and requires additional server resources.

The second option involves moving all database access into stored procedures. Then you set up the Active Directory group accounts to only have execute permissions to the appropriate stored procedures. In this way, the stored procedures comprise a de-facto API. The weakness here is it can limit reporting options.

So what would I do in your shoes? Probably go for the group-based integrated security option, without using the special Application Roles (no  `sp_setapprole`... using Sql Server roles for assigning permissions to your groups is still a good idea). However, I would try to restrict permissions on those groups as much as possible. This way, the only change needed initially in your application is to the connection string. Then we can move towards the stored procedure option over time. This can be done in the application over several release cycles, so you don't need to wait to make the change to integrated security.

Comment: Why would merely adding a database user linked to the AD account grant anything other than `CONNECT`? You'd have to opt-in to enable that user to do anything, wouldn't you?

Comment: @TomW Yes, but the same is true of the original Sql authentication accounts. This was covered in the answer (create a role in Sql Server, assigning permissions to the role, adding the AD login to the role). You have to do that basic work at some point no matter what option you use.  Also, I've updated the answer some to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: Thanks @JoelCoehoorn for the detailed reply. You rightly said about providing the user direct access to the database as we just want the user to connect via our application and that was the reason, we thought of providing access to the applications via service account, not the users. It can be easily done in web apps,  services etc. For thick clients, it's an issue. It seems there is no cleaner way for service accounts. AD groups could be an option but again it's a group of users.. we also want to provide limited access to each service account based on the role.. continued...

Comment: ... and user could be moving departments so we'll have to take care if they are in groups this is additional management. I'm not sure at this point what to do.. we already implemented service account for all the web apps and services/jobs and this only small part. I will explore little more.

Answer (score -1):

Along with Joel's answer regarding AD groups assigned to SQL permissions, it may be in your best interest to create sql views for data reads and stored procs for updates, just assign the sql login mapped to your AD group perms to those items instead of the whole shabang. This will add a layer of abstraction between your end user and your raw database if the end user was so technically inclined to go exploring.

BUT depending on your business case this may be waaaay over-architecting things.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks for the heads up, would be useful if downvoter would educate us on their opinion on why this is bad practice, most of use are here to share and learn...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't think about mapping sql login to ad groups. Thanks again for that. However, this may too much as you suggested.