# C# more secure connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I've just inherited a nightmare of a C# project from a former employee. This application connects to an publicly visible SQL Server (not running on port 1433 at least). Customer's are spread across the globe so it's not possible to just passlist certain IP's.

Using an SQL login and database connection details from a plaintext connection string stored in app.config, a user's login credentials entered into the application are queried against a "User Info" table and if valid another connection string is returned providing login details to their relevant database. Any tech savvy user is currently able to extract the SQL login and database details and use SSMS to directly access the database...

Looking for recommendations on how to resolve the numerous security issues in this car-crash of an implementation. I have a feeling connection strings and direct connection to the SQL server are out of the question for the obvious security issues, and instead configuring a VPN or running queries via an API...?

Comment: In terms of infrastructure what are you using  - would you be able to use Azure key vault for example?

Comment: Yep that would be a possiblity, SQL Server instance is currently running on an Azure VM.

Comment: In terms of your initial database connection could you store the connection string in key vault and use managed service identity to connect to it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/keyvault-msi-appservice-sample/). In terms of the subsequent connection strings you probably want to fundamentally change the design but in the meantime could you not restrict them to the IP address to that of the applications which connect to them?

Comment: Not a complete solution, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404432/service-account-to-connect-database-in-winforms-app/58418943#58418943  In short, the best solution involves rearchitecting and rewriting the app use an application service layer/API that does not directly expose the database.

Comment: Thanks, I've no problems with having to re-write/architect the app. Just wanted to ensure that adding an API or similar would be a recommended solution.

Comment: Windows is a secure operating system because when data is transferred between two computers it is encrypted.  For this to occur you have to put the local and remote computers in the same group and the group has a private encryption key.  When SSQL Server has Integrated Security = true the user credential are used for access privilege.   Integrated Security requires the local and remote computers to be in the same group (so the data is encrypted) and the user has an account on both local and remote machine (or in a user group account that is on both local and remote machine).